# Need MD5 guideline

Tags: encryption, encoding, md5

Is there any specific algorithm for the encoding and decoding MD5. Kindly give me the proper direction or guideline, so that I can move on.. I have search a lot on Google but I haven't find, kindly give the articles or tutorial link.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914461/crc32-and-md5-algorithms-for-dummies

Comment: Do you want to implement MD5 on your own, or do you just want to use MD5 in your application? Almost every language has an implementation of MD5, so you don't have to implement it, unless your interests are purely academic.

Comment: I want to implement MD5, so that firstly I want to take an idea of algorithm, because I haven't listen MD5 before today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MD5 is a hashing algorithm, which by definition is (supposed to be) un-decodable. For a description of the algorithm, read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm).

However, you rarely need to implement the algorithm yourself because most platforms come with an implementation.

First google hit: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmd5-rfc/

Comment: I am working in ANSI C, is there any library in ANSI C for MD5??

Answer (score 2):

MD5, does not "encode" or "decode". MD5 transforms a variable-size input (up to many many terabytes) into a fixed-size output (128 bits, aka 16 bytes). The point of MD5 is to not allow the inverse transformation to be computed.

The [MD5 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321) is short, easy to read, and includes test vectors and a C implementation. Many programming languages/environments already include MD5 implementations. There are also many independent cryptographic libraries which offer MD5 implementations in various languages; you may want to have a look at [sphlib](http://www.crypto-hash.fr/modules/wfdownloads/singlefile.php?cid=13&lid=10) which includes optimized code for MD5 in both C and Java.

Note, though, that MD5 is now considered to be cryptographically weak. In particular, ways have been found to efficiently compute collisions (two distinct inputs with the same output), something which a good hash function should not allow (collision necessarily exist for any hash function, but it should not be feasible to actually compute such collisions; for MD5 it is quite easy [about 14 seconds worth of CPU on a basic PC]).

Comment: if MD5 can't inverse transform then what is the purpose of MD5? Only fixed the size? Where we can use MD5??

Comment: The point of a hash function (such as MD5) is to compute a one-way digest of the document, into a fixed-size format. This is the first step for computing digital signatures, or for many integrity-check procedures. MD5 is _not_ an encryption function.